# Trouble setting up a Hadoop single node on MacOS High Sierra

Tags: java, hadoop, localhost, macos-high-sierra

I am having trouble setting up a Hadoop single node on a Mac. Hadoop seems to start up without errors, but when I go to any of the localhost web addresses mentioned in various (sometimes conflicting) instructions I found on the Net about setting up a Hadoop single node, I get the response, "This site cannot be reached." These localhost locations are the following:

```
localhost:50070
localhost:9870
localhost:8088
```

I also found an instruction which suggested I needed to start Apache using the following instruction:

```
sudo apachectl start
```

After doing this I restarted Hadoop and tried the addresses above in Chrome again, but all remained inaccessible.

I did notice a few nodes that should supposedly start, but did not. These are:

```
NameNode
JobTracker
```

This makes me suspect that even though it had started without error, it actually has not fully started. I'm not an Apache expert or a Hadoop expert, so I think I am now at the limit of my ability to troubleshoot what is going on. Does anyone know if I need the nodes above running and if so, how can I figure out why they are not?

Alternatively, has anyone found a cloud installation of Hadoop which would allow me to do some free test runs of Java-based queries? I need to practice this for an exam, but I don't necessarily need to do it with my own installation of Hadoop. I managed to find this service called Cloudera Hue (Hadoop User Experience), but it seems to only allow SQL-like queries, not Java:

```
https://www.cloudera.com/products/open-source/apache-hadoop/hue.html
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hadoop does **not** need Apache HTTP server. And Hue can run Spark code (in notebooks) and Java code (via Oozie), but you actually need a Hadoop cluster running first.

Comment: Also, which version of Hadoop did you install?? JobTracker doesn't exist in Hadoop2.x or 3.x. You should go look at the NameNode logs files to find out why they did not start.

Answer (score 0):

My lecturer pointed out that if I am only testing Java programs on a local node on my laptop I don't actually need to install or configure anything. All I need to do is download the latest Hadoop binary. Once I have done that I can put the Java files in the Hadoop folder and compile and Jar them from there. He was right: this worked perfectly.